# Quality center 10 with crystal reporting

Tags: reporting, center

We are planning to create crystal reports on QC 10. I was wondering if there is any built-in support in QC 10 for crystal report. I will like to you know the best way to use crystal reporting in QC 10.

Is such thing possible or is there a recommended workaround to that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The examples I have seen use the ActiveX controls to connect things up.  Since the data is all stored in a SQL Server instance, you could technically hit the DB directly (if you know the table structure).  Here's a forum thread on the HP site dealing with exactly that kind of solution: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-Quality-Center-Forum/Connection-between-QC-and-Crystal-Reports/td-p/4627218